# NoClassDefFoundError when implementing AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider in Keycloak extension

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I try to implement a custom OAuth social login provider for Keycloak. My blueprint is the implementation of the [Facobook social login privider](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/social/facebook) in the keycloak code.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I can build the JAR file and move it to `{KECLOAK_HOME}/standalone/deployments/`. The JAR  has a `org.keycloak.broker.social.SocialIdentityProviderFactory` to register my my provider and is recognized by the Keycloak. I can see my new social login provider in the Identity Providers dropdown. Untill this point everything is ok.

My problem is, when i selct this provider, i get an error with the following log:

```
14:01:35,759 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (default task-11) Failed to define class de.klett.keycloak.idp.DemologinIdentityProvider in Module "deployment.idp-demlogin.jar" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link de/keycloak/idp/demologin/DemologinIdentityProvider (Module "deployment.idp-demologin.jar" from Service Module Loader): org/keycloak/broker/oidc/AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider
```

So, how can i fix this?
How can i make the org/keycloak/broker/oidc/AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider available for my keycloak module?

I dont have a module.xml defined because i'm using the [Keycloak Deployer](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#using-the-keycloak-deployer). The social SPI is a private SPI in Keycloak. Is it even possible to use a private SPI in custom extension?